# Plotly неправильный категориальный субплот

Tags: python, plotly, графики

Я столкнулась с проблемой касательно одного сублота из серии.
Проблема с признаком MonthlyCharges_Category, у которой вот такой формат:

```
['starter', 'standard', 'advanced']
Categories (3, object): ['starter' < 'standard' < 'advanced']
```

Но почему-то график отображается с какими-то числовыми значениями, хотя связанный столбец (некатегориальный и называвшийся иначе) удален. С другим признаком TotalCharges_category, что сделан такой же функцией и по  такому же принципу проблем нет.

```
Target_col = "Target"

nrows = (len(data.columns) - 1) // 4 + 1
ncols = min(len(data.columns), 4)


fig = make_subplots(rows=nrows, cols=ncols, subplot_titles=data.columns.drop(target_col), vertical_spacing=0.1)

for i, col in enumerate(data.columns.drop(target_col)):
    row = i // ncols + 1
    col = i % ncols + 1
    trace1 = go.Histogram(x=data[data[target_col] == 0][data.columns[i]], name="0", marker_color='blue',\
                          opacity=0.5, showlegend=False)
    trace2 = go.Histogram(x=data[data[target_col] == 1][data.columns[i]], name="1", marker_color='red', opacity=0.5,\
                         showlegend=False)
    fig.add_trace(trace1, row=row, col=col)
    fig.add_trace(trace2, row=row, col=col)
    fig.update_xaxes(row=row, col=col, title_font=dict(size=12), tickfont=dict(size=10))    
    

fig.update_traces(showlegend=False, selector=dict(type='histogram'))
fig.update_layout(height=1200, width=1000, title_text="Class Balance")
fig.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура даннных выглядит так:

| MonthlyCharges_category | TotalCharges_category | ClientAgeDays |
| --- | --- | --- |
| starter | standard | 145 |
| advanced | starter | 1492 |

print колонки:

```
0        starter
1       standard
2       standard
3       standard
4       advanced
          ...   
7038    advanced
7039    advanced
7040     starter
7041    advanced
7042    advanced
Name: MonthlyCharges_category, Length: 7043, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): ['no' < 'starter' < 'standard' < 'advanced']
```

К сожалению, никак не получилось избавиться. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: вообще, конечно, надо бы приводить исходные данные в воспроизводимом виде в таких вопросах. а для дебагинга  просто попробовать отдельно вывести график с проблемной колонкой, а не в куче со всеми остальными сабплотами.

Comment: вот в начале цикла вы удаляете колонку `for i, col in enumerate(data.columns.drop(target_col))`. Но потом-то вы все равно обращаетесь к оригинальному датафрейму, где колонка не удалена.

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал с рандомными данными. У MonthlyCharges_category и TotalCharges_category ось х одинаковая. т.к. график ClientAgeDays похож на ваш график MonthlyCharges_category, предполагаю, что при построении, данные как то между собой перемешиваются.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from random import randint
import pandas as pd


a = 250
d = {0:'starter', 1:'standard', 2:'advanced'}
a1 = [d[randint(0, 2)] for i in range(a)]
a2 = [d[randint(0, 2)] for i in range(a)]
a3 = [randint(0, 120) for i in range(a)]
data = pd.DataFrame({'MonthlyCharges_category':a1, 'TotalCharges_category':a2, 'ClientAgeDays':a3})
data['Target'] = 0

#target_col не было, поэтому переименовал Target_col
target_col = "Target"


nrows = (len(data.columns) - 1) // 4 + 1
ncols = min(len(data.columns), 4)


fig = make_subplots(rows=nrows, cols=ncols, subplot_titles=data.columns.drop(target_col), vertical_spacing=0.1)

for i, col in enumerate(data.columns.drop(target_col)):
    row = i // ncols + 1
    col = i % ncols + 1
    trace1 = go.Histogram(x=data[data[target_col] == 0][data.columns[i]], name="0", marker_color='blue',\
                          opacity=0.5, showlegend=False)
    trace2 = go.Histogram(x=data[data[target_col] == 1][data.columns[i]], name="1", marker_color='red', opacity=0.5,\
                         showlegend=False)
    fig.add_trace(trace1, row=row, col=col)
    fig.add_trace(trace2, row=row, col=col)
    fig.update_xaxes(row=row, col=col, title_font=dict(size=12), tickfont=dict(size=10))    
    

fig.update_traces(showlegend=False, selector=dict(type='histogram'))
fig.update_layout(height=500, width=1000, title_text="Class Balance")
fig.show()
```